# Theme.Holo doesn't work

Tags: android

I am a newbie and I can't crack problem with themes. I use Android Studio, I have standard 'hello world' app where I am trying to use Theme.Holo on it, so I had set my `minSdkVersion` to `"11"` in my manifest file (I know that it can be used only on 11 and above). Then in styles.XML I change my AppTheme to `android:Theme.Holo`. I can see in my preview that theme has changed properly but when I run my app on my phone (Android 4.2.2 API 17) I get error ' application has been stopped'. When I get back to standard `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` application starts normally.

I was also trying to apply the Theme.Holo directly in manifest file in `application` by `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo", but then it is not displayed in the preview and also is being stopped when trying to run on the phone.`

I've really searched all over for an answer and it is starting to be very frustrating, anyone could help me with this one?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.actiobar_app" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

...

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

    </style>



</resources>
```

//main activity

```
package com.mycompany.actiobar_app;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

logcat

```
02-03 20:47:10.546  24023-24023/? E/SharedPreferenceProvider﹕ onCreate
02-03 20:47:11.226    598-24036/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
02-03 20:47:12.500  24082-24082/? E/SPPClientService﹕ ============PushLog. commonIsShipBuild. stop!
02-03 20:47:12.500  24082-24082/? E/SPPClientService﹕ [PushClientApplication] Push log off : This is Ship build version
02-03 20:47:12.789     116-9832/? E/AudioPolicyService﹕ getParamFromPolicy : enter , keys = situation=1;device=0
02-03 20:47:12.796     116-9832/? E/audio_policy_mrvl﹕ mrvl_ap_getParamFromPolicy: situation=1;device=0
02-03 20:47:12.882      598-649/? E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-03 20:47:12.882      598-609/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
02-03 20:47:17.664  24206-24229/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
02-03 20:47:18.117  26884-26884/? E/AuthorizationBluetoothService﹕ Proximity feature is not enabled.
02-03 20:47:30.312     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5949
02-03 20:47:42.750      598-664/? E/lights﹕ write_int failed to open -1
02-03 20:47:47.914      598-649/? E/NotificationService﹕ Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
02-03 20:47:47.976      598-649/? E/NotificationService﹕ Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
02-03 20:47:48.000      598-647/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
02-03 20:47:48.000      598-647/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
02-03 20:47:48.000      598-647/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
02-03 20:47:48.000      598-647/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
02-03 20:47:48.046      598-647/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
02-03 20:47:48.046      598-647/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
02-03 20:47:48.046      598-647/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
02-03 20:47:48.046      598-647/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
02-03 20:47:48.093      598-647/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/lens_flare_tap.ogg
02-03 20:47:48.093      598-647/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/lens_flare_unlock.ogg
02-03 20:47:48.210      598-649/? E/NotificationService﹕ Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
02-03 20:48:00.312     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5950
02-03 20:48:30.312     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5951
02-03 20:49:00.320     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5952
02-03 20:49:06.390  24306-24306/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onIsLanguageAvailable() - lang : pol, country : POL, variant : , iResult : -2
02-03 20:49:06.390  24306-24306/? E/﹕ Samsung TTS Engine - initialize() : Samsung TTS Engine (released - 201302151)
02-03 20:49:06.390  24306-24306/? E/﹕ Samsung TTS Engine - initialize() : ro.product.manufacturer - samsung
02-03 20:49:06.625  24306-24320/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onIsLanguageAvailable() - lang : eng, country : USA, variant : , iResult : 1
02-03 20:49:06.625  24306-24320/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onLoadLanguage() - LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE
02-03 20:49:06.625  24306-24320/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onLoadLanguage() - lang : eng, country : USA, variant : f01
02-03 20:49:30.320     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5953
02-03 20:50:00.320     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5954
02-03 20:50:30.320     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5955
02-03 20:50:40.960    2639-2639/? E/SPPClientService﹕ [[PushClientService]] onStartCommand. F:false, D:false, E:false, T:false, S:false, R:false
02-03 20:51:00.320     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5956
02-03 20:51:30.320     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5957
02-03 20:51:41.320  20425-20463/? E/PlayEventLogger﹕ Upload failed class java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname)
02-03 20:52:00.328     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5958
02-03 20:52:30.328     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5959
02-03 20:53:00.328     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5960
02-03 20:53:30.328     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5961
02-03 20:54:00.328     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5962
02-03 20:54:30.328     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5963
02-03 20:55:00.328     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5964
02-03 20:55:30.335     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5965
02-03 20:56:00.335     598-1004/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5966
```

Comment: Show us your logcat.

Comment: Hey, i've added logcat, could you please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be is that your `Activity` is probably extending `ActionBarActivity`, which means that you **have** to use an `AppCompat` theme (or descendant).

Comment: I thought that after API 11 you can use Theme.Holo in every app...any idea how I can bypass this ?

Comment: Post your `Activity` and Logcat code so we can see what is going on

Comment: just added acitivity and logcat, hope this is what meant by logcat, i've filtered only by errors because it was too many lines and i didnt know how to stop session

Comment: As I suspected. You are using `ActionBarActivity`, which **requires** `AppCompat`.

Comment: well it was standard code, and i dont know yet how all this works, so what should code look like to use `Theme.Holo`? I've read about suport libraries:" `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` when using the Support Library.
•`android.app.ActionBar` when developing only for API level 11 or higher." The v7 library can use only `AppCompat` and descendants, so I think I should use`android.app.ActionBar` library but how?

Comment: Either don't `extend `ActionBarActivity` or choose another theme

Comment: It works! I've used `extends Activity ` and imported  `android.app.Activity;` library and it works like a charm. Spended 5 days in searching for solution, thank you!